# Swift Unwind Segue: how to know which row initiated original segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm programmatically initiating a segue in a custom table view row action. When that segue unwinds I need to know which row did initiate the segue, but `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` is nil.

Is there some way for me to know the which row did it?

On the TableViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit") { action, index in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditObject", sender: tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath))
    }
    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightBlue
}

@IBAction func unwindToObjectList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? EditObjectTableViewController, let object = sourceViewController.object {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            objects[selectedIndexPath.row] = object
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
        } else {
            print("Could not find selected row…") // <- this is printed!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` returns `nil` in `prepareForSegue` also?

Comment: Hi.
It's already `nil` in `prepareForSegue`…

Comment: So, may be the row doesn't get selected. Check whether the delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` gets called.

Comment: In `didSelectRow at:`, remember the selection in a property `var lastSelectedRow:IndexPath?`.

Comment: Code patch is required. Update the question with the selection code.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi: you're right, the row does not get selected.

Comment: Is there any other way to know the row which triggered the segue, or should I save the row index in a property, as @shallowThought suggested?

Comment: Can't you select it programmatically? : ' self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none) ' in your closure before the segue - it seems like you want to swipe to segue hence the editactions

Comment: That's exactly right! Worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Pass the indexPath as the `sender` to `performSegueWithIdentifier` then you can set a property on the destination view controller and then read this same property n your unwind method.